# Change all td color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change all my 4'th cell (I give id 'zal') background if value less than 0. I tried to change for each, but only first row change. I try javascript and jquery. It didn't change somehow. Thanks for any help.

```
<table id="ex-table" class="table">
  <tr id="tr" class="mini">

 </table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing:0;

}

th{ 
padding: 10px;
}

td {
    padding: 15px;

}

.mini{
color: black;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
background: #fff;
text-align: center;

}

.redback {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
  var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref("orders").once('value', function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();
                var degis = val[5].replace("pips", "     ");
                var tss = degis.substring(0,7);

                content +='<tr class="mini">';
                content += '<td>' + val[0] + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val[1] + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val[4] + '</td>';
                content += '<td id="zal">' + tss + '</td>';
                content += '</tr>';

                /*var x = document.getElementById("zal");

                if(tss<0){
                x.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }*/



            });

            $('#ex-table').append(content);

        }

        $('#zal').each(function() {

             $(this).addClass('redback');

        });

    });
```

Also it say tss is null when I try like below. Than I tried just change the background color.

```
$('#zal').each(function() {
        if(tss<0){      
                 $(this).addClass('redback');
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please append sample html with your data

Comment: Chris G It's didn't work.No error just didn't work.

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/nxjg59hk/

Comment: first row change because of duplicated ids .. id should be unique so don't use the same id for more than one element .. use class instead

Comment: Chris G It's didn't work.I change my code with pid's answer and actually bg changed but it still error " tss is not defined. " So if,else not work.

Comment: @Dorbagna not defined inside the `.each()` right? ..even if you find a way to make it work it will just gives you the last `tss` from the loop .. So use the text of `.zal` instead of using the `tss`  I mean in `.each()`  use `parseInt($(this).text().trim()) > 0` instead of `tss`

Comment: Now it's work.Thak you so much.https://jsfiddle.net/kekolog/av2sr43k/3/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `id` as if it was `class`.

An `id` must be unique in the whole page by definition. If you have more than one on the same page browsers are free to expose undefined behavior, such as:

- no node has that ID;
- the first node has that ID;
- many nodes have that ID.

But generally, you break the page and if it's HTML5 you're probably falling out of it into compatibility mode.

A `class` on the other hand, is as defined in mathematics a "class" of items. It may contain 0, 1 or more items. So if you want to hit many `<td>` nodes, you must use `class` and not `id`:

```
content += '<td class="zal">' + tss + '</td>';
```

and:

```
$('.zal').each(function() {
  // ...
```

Comment: This is work for bg.But still say tss is not defined